# Change element text in Angular with condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an issue with changing the content of an element in Angular. i am making a tic tac toe game and I put the header every movement the player do, but I want to render in that place when the player wins. Here is the code:

```
<div *ngIf="_state$ | async">
  <p>
  Turn of {{ (_state$ | async).turn == 'PLAYERX' ? "Player 1 - Xs" : "Player 2 - 0s" }}
  </p>
  <p>
  There is a winner {{ (_state$ | async).winner == 'X' ? "Player 1 - Xs" : "Player 2 - 0s" }}
  </p>
</div>
```

how i can do it. To show only once no both if the player wins that show the second

and is the player is playing and is has not win the first. I can only show the first only.

Comment: you can add an *ngIf condition inside the paragraph tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing `(_state$ | async).winner` will only be defined when you have a winner. In that case you can use that as a condition to show the second p and hide the first.

```
<div *ngIf="_state$ | async as state">
  <p *ngIf="!state.winner">
  Turn of {{ state.turn == 'PLAYERX' ? "Player 1 - Xs" : "Player 2 - 0s" }}
  </p>
  <p *ngIf="state.winner">
  There is a winner {{ state.winner == 'X' ? "Player 1 - Xs" : "Player 2 - 0s" }}
  </p>
</div>
```

If the `(_state$ | async).winner` is always defined but has different value when there is no winner, then you'll have to change the condition to reflect that.

Comment: `(_state$ | async).winner` returns 'X' or 'O' not true or false. Your solution doesn't work as of now